# Why is the binding of "this" different in browser than in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was trying to fully understand the difference between normal functions and arrow functions and looked at [this page](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-regular-functions-and-arrow-functions-in-javascript).

```
this.a = 100;
let arrowFunc = () => {this.a = 150};
function regFunc() {
   this.a = 200;
}
console.log(this.a)
arrowFunc()
console.log(this.a)
regFunc()
console.log(this.a)
```

If I copy-paste the example code into the browser, I'm getting 100 150 200 opposed to what's expected in the tutorial. Apparently, "this" declared in normal functions is also pointing to the outer scope in browsers, unlike in Node.js.

Can somebody explaining why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Comment: Node.JS runs in Strict Mode. Browsers don't (by default).

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Node isn't strict by default (at east not v14.7)

Comment: Thank you all! I forgot about the 'strict mode'.

Comment: Might help if you logged `this` to browser console at top level of your code or right in console itself. Will see it is the `window` object

Comment: @TheGabornator: It has nothing to do with strict mode.

Answer (score 3):

The functions behave the same in both Node.js and the browser. It's actually the

`console.log(this.a)`

part that is different.

Code in `<script>` elements in the browser run in global scope. In global scope `this` refers to the global object. This `this.a = 100` will create a global variable `a`.

In Node, most code lives inside *CommonJS modules*. Inside a module, `this` refers to the module's exports (`this === module.exports`), not the global object. Hence `console.log(this.a)` will access the *export* with name `a`, not a global variable.

In both cases `this` inside the "normal" functions, called as functions, refers to the global object.

---

Here is something you can run in both environments to verify whether `this` inside the function and outside of it are the same:

```
const outsideThis = this;

(function() {
  console.log(this === outsideThis);
}());
```

It will be `true` in the browser and `false` in Node.

Run this in Node:

```
exports.a = 42;
global.b = 21;

console.log(this.a, this.b); // 42, undefined (i.e. `this` refers to exports)

(function() { 
  console.log(this.a, this.b); // undefined, 21
}());                          // (i.e. `this` refers to the global object)
```

Comment: "In Node, most code lives inside CommonJS modules. Inside a module, this refers to the module's exports (this === module.exports), not the global object." But if I e.g. declare `this.foo` in a function and then try to console.log it outside of it, it will log `undefined`. Meaning, this is inside of that function and not in the module.

Comment: You mean you do `console.log(this.foo)` outside the function?

Comment: *"Meaning, this is inside of that function and not in the module."* I'm not sure what that means. Most environments have a `this` value. The questions is only what value it really refers to.

Comment: Right `function foo() {this.a = 'bar'}` and then `console.log(this.a)` will print undefined. But in browser, it would print `'bar'`

Comment: For the same reasons I explained: Inside the function `this` refers to the global object, so `this.a = 'bar'` creates a global variable. Inside the module, `this` refers to the exports object, so `console.log(this.a)` tries to log the *export* `a` (which doesn't exist).

Comment: And in the browser, `this` inside the function and in global scope (outside the function) will refer to the global object.

Comment: I misinterpreted your question a bit, but the main point stands: the function behaves the same in both environments, it’s the “this” outside the function that’s different.